# Android instrumented unit testing Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJUnit4'

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-instrumentation, android-junit

I trying to add Android Support Instrumentation test to my application, but i run this problem: **Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJUnit4'**

Its seems i don't have the package `android.support.test.runner`

my app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "---PACKAGENAME---"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../keys/debug.jks")
            storePassword "*"
            keyAlias "debug"
            keyPassword "*"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug_uat {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug_int {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        staging {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

The gradle sync and the build is ok, but i can not add the support AndroidJUnitRunner to my run config and my android test class (the class is in androidTest filder)

Please help!
Apoth

## UPDATE

I found the problem. I using various build types, and i just needed to add `testBuildType "debug_uat"` to my build.gradle.

Comment: Have you read this?  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#setup

Comment: Yes of course, i tried to set up based in this documentation

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, then. You say that the Gradle build is fine, but it wouldn't be fine if a library can't be compiled, so what file are you using that has `AndroidJUnit4`?